# How can I run correct version of compiler when using elevated command prompt

Tags: windows-7, environment-variables, uac

I have two versions of the Typescript compiler (tsc.exe) on my system (1.0 and 1.5) and I cannot remove the earlier one because it is installed with Visual Studio 2013.

They are located at:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\tsc.exe
```

and

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.5\tsc.exe
```

I have gone and changed my system's PATH to point to the newer one's directory..

If I run the compiler from the command line by typing `tsc.exe` as my user account I get the correct one.

If I run the compiler from the command line with UAC I get the wrong (old) one.

How can I get my system to use the newer one under an elevated command prompt?

Comment: Use the command >Path in the CmdPrompt in both different methods of running, for a clue?

Comment: It shows the same thing when I run UAC or regular user prompt. When I type tsc -v in each one I get a different version.

Comment: One other thing i am getting from the web (doing search) is if the permissions were different , but that would assume that both are within the path, and it is running one based on allowable permission.  The sys wide path thing registry location is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment   In win8 they somehow changed things so users path is not effecting the sys path, i dont even know where the users path is :-)  a lot of help i am.

Comment: That registry key says the new one like the others. I did forget to mention that I am using a Visual Studio command prompt but not sure if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: Looking more into it I think it is the Visual Studio command prompt that is causing this.

Comment: Another thing I though of, which may be valueless too, If the initial executable , is only a starter for other parts and pieces of the program. Like in a game you could have a "launcher" that starts a game but the path would still be important to what executable it would end up running.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Confirmed this is happening because of the Visual Studio command prompt.

Comment: cool, so now you can fix this ?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/f2ccy3wt(v=vs.120).aspx  & https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/kezkeayy.aspx so it works like you wanted?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how to change it but when I look at the VS2013 path more closely I see that it has the 1.0 version first. I'm looking into it.

Comment: I think it is doing a recursive on the directory and adding it. I think I would need to either rename tsc.exe to something else or delete the directory.